# AES key from encrypted text and IV

Tags: aes, ciphertext-only-attack

So I'm trying to figure out if it's possible to extract the private key if you have the ciphertext and the IV corresponding to that ciphertext. 
It's for some kind of a challenge, and can't really seem to figure it out.

Comment: It's usually called a *secret* key instead of a private key for symmetric block ciphers such as AES. If anybody takes up this challenge for a well randomized AES key then I would consider them challenged indeed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, that's not really possible without blatant flaws of the implementation. Modern modes of operation of ciphers are resistent to attacks even if you know many pairs of plaintext and ciphertext - and the IV is public knowledge. Knowing it is the normal case. You also didn't mention what operation mode was used.

Well, of course you could brute force the key, but that would take more time and computational power than you can ever muster.

Oh, and a small note: AES is a symmetric cipher, so there's just one key, which is normally not called private key. It may be true, but this term is generally reserved for asymmetric encryption.

Answer (score 0):

We know this is theoretically possible, but your search space is 2^126 right now and no sign of this improving. Good luck building enough supercomputer (all the computers on the planet combined aren't even close right now).